# A curious eigenvalue inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities

Suppose $A, B$ are positive definite Hermitian matrices, $U$ is a unitary matrix such that $AUB$ is Hermitian. The spectral radius of a square matrix $X$ is denoted by $\rho(X)$. In my study, I guessed an inequality
$$\rho(U^*AU+B)\le \rho(A+B).$$
That is, the largest eigenvalue of $U^*AU+B$ is no larger than the largest eigenvalue of $A+B$.  How to prove it?

The condition $AUB$ being Hermitian is indispensible, but I have no clue how to use it.

Comment: Denoting $C=U^*AU$ we get $UCB=AUB=R$ is Hermitian, so $CB=U^*R$. That is, $U$ comes from the polar decomposition of $CB$, if $R$ is additionally assumed to be positive definite.

Comment: Another observation (though somewhat beside the point) is that $U(n)$ has (real) dimension $n^2$, and you're imposing exactly that many conditions, so typically there will probably only be finitely many $U$'s satisfying your assumption for given $A,B$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling in generic situation yes, but if $CB^2C$ has multiple eigenvalue, there are infinitely many Hermitian matrices $R$ satisfying $R^2=BC^2B$, for each of them $U^*:=CBR^{-1}$ is unitary.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: thanks, at least I could see an equivalent statement of the question: If $B, C$ are positive definite and $U$ is unitary such that $UCB$ is Hermitian, then $\rho(C+B)\le \rho(UCU^*+B)$.

Comment: Can you say what your reasons are to believe that the inequality is true?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I sent via email the background.

Comment: Thank you Minghua for your email. My simulations, too, so far support your conjecture.

Comment: Some easy suggestions: (i) note that $U=BC(CB^2C)^{-1/2}$, where $C$ is as in the comments by Fedor Petrov and M. Lin. (ii) Let $L:=C+B$ and $R:=UCU^*+B$. Then it suffices to show that $\text{tr}(L^k)\le\text{tr}(R^k)$ for all (large enough) natural $k$. This inequality trivially holds for $k=1$, and numerical experiments suggests it holds for all natural $k$. An advantage of the latter inequality is that it is polynomial in the elements of the matrices $L$ and $R$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis it may be non-positive square root!

Comment: @FedorPetrov : That's right; there can be an extra factor on the right, which is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries of modulus $1$.

Comment: I don't have an answer nor do I have the reputation to comment on the previous comments, but it occurred to me to look at what happens when you iterate this operation. That is given A and B construct $U$, let $A=U^*AU$ and repeat. It seems that going in the forward direction, eventually the matrices $A$ and $B$ commute with the eigenvalues of $A$ matched with the eigenvalues of $B$ so that largest is paired with largest. If you run the iteration in reverse, again they eventually commute but at the end the eigenvalues are paired sorted so that the largest of $A$ is paired with smallest of $B$ a

Comment: @rucarden Not sure if I understand you correctly, but your way constructing $U$ does not guarantee $AUB$ to be Hermitian?

Comment: Could there exist a completely positive map that maps $A+B$ to $U^* A U + B$ and the identity to itself ?
If yes this would be the solution.

Comment: If we set $R=B^{-1} A U$ then $R$ is Hermitian and we have to show :
$\rho((R B^2 R)^{1/2} + B)\le \rho((B R^2 B)^{1/2} + B)$ .

Comment: With the notation I used in my previous comment the conjectured inequality $tr((U^*AU+B)^2) \le tr((A+B)^2)$ is then equivalent to
$tr((R B^2 R)^{1/2} B) \le tr((B R^2 B)^{1/2} B)$ .

Comment: @jjcale I knew a proof of $tr((U^*AU+B)^2) \le tr((A+B)^2)$, my proof relies on THEOREM 4.3 in the paper 'Inequalities related to $2\times 2$ block PPT matrices, Oper. & Matrices, 9 (2015) 917-924.' I will email you the proof details if you want.

Comment: I am generating $U$ in the manner suggested by the discussion above.
We want $$AUB=BU^*A$$ so assume that $AU=BH$ where $H$ is a Hermitian matrix. Then $A^2=BH^2B$, and I get $H$ from taking the positive square root of $B^{-1}A^2B^{-1}$, and then $U=A^{-1}BH$. As the discussion above suggests, different roots could be used for generating $H$. And having thought about this a little more, I would say the resulting iterations seems more like a modified Duggal iteration.

Comment: If the condition would be that $A^{1/2} U B^{1/2}$ is Hermitian then it would not be difficult to proof the inequality.

Comment: @jjcale: yes, you are right. Part of the motivation for the question comes from this observation.

Comment: It seems a stronger result is true.  That is the eigenvalues of $U^*AU+B$ are majorized by the eigenvalues of $A+B$.

Comment: @rucarden This is also my conjecture,^_^

Comment: Was the motivation for the inequality the operator $T(U)=AU^*B$.  This inequality must have something to do with doing the power method with this operator and normalizing using a polar factorization.  $$T(U_i)=U_{i+1}^*P_{i+1}$$

Comment: @rucarden: Frankly speaking, I did not think of this before.

Comment: If you consider the iteration proposed involving $T(U)$, and let $U_0=I$, then the eigenvalues of $AB$ are log majorized by the eigenvalues of $AU_1B$.  This is because the $AB$ and $AU_1B$ are similar.  Unfortunately, I don't see how this can be used to prove the desired inequality.

Answer (score 2):

I still don't have enough reputations points to comment but here is another related iteration.  Geometrically the inequality says that using the matrix $U$ to transform $A$ moves the hyperellipse associated with $A$ further away from the hyperellipse associated with $B$. This has something to do with the angles between the eigenvectors of $A$, $U^*AU$ and $B$.

If we diagonalize $A=V_A\Lambda_AV_A^*$ and $B=V_B\Lambda_BV_B^*,$
then $$AUB=V_A\Lambda_A V_A^*UV_B\Lambda_B V_B^*$$.  Taking a similarity transformation with $V_A\Lambda_A$ and letting  $\Theta_2=V_A^*UV_B$ and $\Theta_1=V_A^*V_B$ denote the matrices whose entries have the information regarding the angles between the eigenvectors of $A$ , $U^*AU$ and $B$, then we have 
$$H_1=\Theta_2\Lambda_B \Theta_1^*\Lambda_A^{-1} $$
which is a Hermitian matrix.  We have 
$$ H_1\Lambda_A\Theta_1=\Theta_2\Lambda_B$$
At the next iteration we would have 
$$ H_2\Lambda_A\Theta_2=\Theta_3\Lambda_B$$
Eliminating $\Theta_3$, we have
$$ H_2^2=\Lambda_A^{-1}\Theta_2\Lambda_B^2\Theta_2^*\Lambda_A^{-1},$$
and now eliminating $\Lambda_B$ and $\Theta_2$ and taking a square root,
$$H_2=(\Lambda_A^{-1}H_1\Lambda_A^2H_1\Lambda_A^{-1})^{1/2}.$$
$\Lambda_B$ is absent from this iteration though it can be recovered.  It seems that the 2-norm of the $H_i$ is increasing and that $H_i$ must converge to $\Lambda_B\Lambda_A^{-1}$ where the eigenvalues of $A$ are in ascending order and the eigenvalues of $B$ are in descending order.

Comment: Thanks for the comments... it is not clear to me what this would lead to?